# Create HTML-Link that calls a js-function, within a js-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to represent the results of a search. Next to some information, the user can click on the title and get to a detail-page.

```
var resultDiv = "<div id='results_container'>"; 

    $.each( result, function(i, poi) {
        resultDiv += "<div class=\"result\">";
        resultDiv += "<p class=\"date\">" + "Date: " + poi.date + ", Category: " + poi.category + "</p>";
        resultDiv += "<p class=\"title\"><a id='link' onClick='loadPOI(poi)' href='#markerdetail-page'>" + poi.title + "</a></p>";
        resultDiv += "<p class=\"description\">" + poi.description.substring(0,200) + "</p>";
        resultDiv += "</div>";
    });
    resultDiv += "</div>";
```

The link in the dynamically created HTML-Code always calls the function with the parameter of the latest element. How to call the function with the parameter of the current poi-element?

Comment: I would expect it to throw an error due to poi being undefined when you click it.

Comment: You shouldn't have elements with the same `id`, if you do not want to mess up queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where it would make more sense to actually create elements within the iteration rather than after, that way you can properly reference `poi` and assign click events.

```
var resultDiv = $("<div id='results_container'>"); 

$.each( result, function(i, poi) {
    var div = $("<div class='result'>");
    div.append("<p class=\"date\">" + "Date: " + poi.date + ", Category: " + poi.category + "</p>");
    div.append("<p class=\"title\"><a id='link' href='#markerdetail-page'>" + poi.title + "</a></p>");
    div.append("<p class=\"description\">" + poi.description.substring(0,200) + "</p>");
    div.find("a").click(function(){
        loadPOI(poi);
    });
    resultDiv.append(div);
});

resultDiv.appendTo("#someel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you want to pass the POI title when a link is clicked then you can do it like this.

var resultDiv = "";

```
$.each( result, function(i, poi) {
    resultDiv += "<div class=\"result\">";
    resultDiv += "<p class=\"date\">" + "Date: " + poi.date + ", Category: " + poi.category + "</p>";
    resultDiv += "<p class=\"title\"><a id='link' onClick='loadPOI(this)' href='#markerdetail-page'>" + poi.title + "</a></p>";
    resultDiv += "<p class=\"description\">" + poi.description.substring(0,200) + "</p>";
    resultDiv += "</div>";
});
resultDiv += "</div>";
```

I have changed loadPOI(poi) to loadPOI(this) within the link. This will pass the currently clicked element as object to loadPOI() so you can get the poi title from that object in loadPOI() function.

```
function loadPOI(obj) {
  var title = obj.text();
  console.log(title);
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: "this" gives the complete html-file as an object to the function.